# How can I use the information that's returned after an ajax .fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set up the following:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/Contents/GetCitiess",
    data: { accountID: AccountID }
})
    .done(function (data) {
        city.html(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });


function ajaxOnFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    "use strict";
    alert("Network connection " + textStatus);
}
```

Is there a better way that I could be using the .fail information. I would like to provide more information but I am not sure what I could provide and how I could do this. Note this is an internal application so I want to give as much failure information as possible.

Comment: May be you can show error info to the user in html ..

Comment: well if `errorThrown` exists you know it's a HTTP error.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit about errorThrown?

Comment: From the docs: *When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."* - read more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The fail information can be used in certain scenarios like below.

if you have authentication in your application, then you can use the fail information to determine session timeout and redirect user to login page

similarly you can show the exception message that occurred in back end in the screen using the fail information

above are the scenarios that i have encountered. There may be other scenarios based on the application and needs